# Pronoun: one vs it

Tags: grammar, differences, pronouns

According to the following explanation of using ‘one’ in Oxford Practice Grammar:

> We use  ‘one’ to talk about an object in general (6) and ‘it’ for a
> specific example of an object (7):
>
> (6) Do you have **a** French dictionary? I am looking for **one** (= not a specific French
> dictionary)
> (7) Do you have **the** French dictionary? I am looking for **it** (=  a specific French dictionary)

Now, I have a question :
The following context is extracted from another book:

> Learning a language as a child seems to involve no effort, but
> learning **it** as an adult requires a lot of time and effort.

In the above sentence *a language* is used in general, but why does the writer use *it* instead of *one*?

Comment: "It" is a back reference to "a language" (i.e. the same language"). "One" would imply any language, not necessarily the same as the one previously referred to.

Comment: The more I read that sentence ("Learning a langu..."), the more it sounds weird/wrong. The 'a' and 'it' make for a strange pairing, even if such a choice might be grammatically correct. It would only sound right to me if a specific language was mentioned in a previous sentence.

Answer (score 15):

In the sentence

> Learning **a language** as a child seems to involve no effort, but learning **it** as an adult requires a lot of time and effort.

*a language* has been mentioned in the gerund clause, so it may serve as an antecedent for *it*, which occurs later on in the sentence. There is therefore a slight implication that the two languages are the same, as in

> Learning English as a child seems to involve no effort, but learning English as an adult requires a lot of time and effort.

The sentence

> Learning a language as a child seems to involve no effort, but learning **one** as an adult requires a lot of time and effort.

uses the indefinite pronoun *one*, which does not refer to a specific syntactic entity in general (and in particular not to any entity already introduced in the sentence). Now the sense is that children seem to learn any language with no effort, but it's hard to learn any language as an adult. The languages need not be the same, as in

> Learning **a language** as a child seems to involve no effort (even a difficult language like Basque), but learning one (even a comparatively simple language like Spanish) as an adult requires a lot of time and effort.

Comment: If the author didn't intend that implication then using "it" would be incorrect?

Comment: @talrnu I wouldn't go so far as incorrect. Using *it* introduces some ambiguity. The first gerund clause has "a language", any language in general because it's the first use of *language*. The second gerund clause uses the personal pronoun *it*, which refers to a particular language. The only antecedent is *a language* in the first gerund clause, which will force the reader to adjust the meaning after the fact. That doesn't happen in the *English...English* example.